# LogCat won't stop scrolling my logs when log limit is reached

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm using the latest SDK Tools R15 and if my LogCat is full (top-most logs are removed when a new log is added) and I'm scrolled in the middle of the current logs, my logs are still scrolling upward. I can't get the logs I'm looking at to be stationary. I would rather it move my scroll location with the logs as they are scrolling. It seemed to have this behavior in previous versions but it stopped doing that in R15. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to R16 fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I never figured out how to get the Eclipse-attached Logcat to stop scrolling, which is why I recommend using a separate terminal/command line for watching the log.

```
cd path/to/android_sdk/platform-tools
./adb logcat
```

Comment: Yeah, it's what I've been using in the mean time. Definitely not ideal though.